# Extract multiple json fields using nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm new to Nifi. I have below json structure to be implemented using Nifi..

```
{
  "jobs": [
      {
            "jid": "1",
            "name": "job1",
            "state": "FAILED",
            "start-time": 12243
      },
      {
            "jid": "2",
            "name": "job2",
            "state": "FAILED",
            "start-time": 1233
      },
      {
            "jid": "3",
            "name": "job2",
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "start-time": 1223213
      }

  ]
}
```

I need the output to be like below filtered only FAILED job details

```
{
  [
  job1,
  job2
  ]
}
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This spec will output a JSON array [job1,job2]:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "jobs": {
        "*": {
          "state": {
            "FAILED": {
              "@(2,name)": "[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Your desired output of an array inside braces is not valid JSON, as objects need key/value pairs. If instead you want the array in an object, let's call the key `failed_jobs` and you can use the following spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "jobs": {
        "*": {
          "state": {
            "FAILED": {
              "@(2,name)": "failed_jobs[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```